# "I will come within 2 hours." or "I will come in 2 hours."

Tags: prepositions

> I will come within 2 hours.
> I will come in 2 hours.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

**Within 2 hours** = before two hours have passed.
At any time in the next 120 minutes.

**In 2 hours** = two hours from now.
After 120 minutes have passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you will come before the end of two hours, you use the preposition "within".

If you mean that you will come before the end of two hours or when two hours have passed, you use the preposition "in".